# Unable to specify image upload path - ionic 3

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap

I'm trying to upload an image using ionic app to a php server after cropping through image Picker. The image does not exist in the path it shows.

Is there any way to specify a path for saving cropped image?

This is my code:

```
getImage()
{
  var options = {
   maximumImagesCount: 1,
   width: 800,
   height: 800,
   quality: 80,
  };

 this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
 .then((results) => {
   this.reduceImages(results).then(() => {
        this.photos = results;

        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

            let d = new Date();
            let time = d.getTime();
            let options_f: FileUploadOptions = {
              fileKey: 'file',
              fileName: this.name + time + '.jpg',
              chunkedMode: false,
              mimeType: "image/jpg",
            };

            let url='https://elevather.com/mentor/file_upload.php';

            fileTransfer.upload(this.photos, url, options_f)
            .then((data) => {
              if(data["_body"]=="yes")
                this.msg = 'yes';
              else
                this.msg = 'no';
            }, (err) => {
              console.log('upload failed!');
            });

    }, (err) => { });
  }, (err) => { });
}

reduceImages(selected_pictures: any) : any{
  return selected_pictures.reduce((promise:any, item:any) => {
    return promise.then((result) => {
      return this.cropService.crop(item, {quality: 80})
       .then(cropped_image => console.log('Done'));
     });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Is there any other way I can do so?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to access this path ? this is where it gets saved (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop/blob/master/src/android/CropPlugin.java).

```
 private String getTempDirectoryPath() {
    File cache = null;

    // SD Card Mounted
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        cache = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/Android/data/" + cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/cache/");
    }
    // Use internal storage
    else {
        cache = cordova.getActivity().getCacheDir();
    }

    // Create the cache directory if it doesn't exist
    cache.mkdirs();
    return cache.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you tell me what can be done for ios?

Comment: This is the path I get in an android device: file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/tmp_Screenshot_20180905-2112141360997663.png

Comment: did you try to add the return value to your function like this?

 this.reduceImages(results).then((imagePath) => { console.log(imagePath);

        this.photos = results;

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have now added a return value. But the returned value I'm getting is undefined.

Comment: I think you need to add the following also: .then(cropped_image => cropped_image); so the cropped_image is also returned.

Comment: This is what I've done:      this.reduceImages(results).then((croppedImage) => { this.photos = croppedImage; });

Comment: i meant to replace the console.log in the reduceImages() function with the line I posted :)

Comment: Thank you :) Now I'm getting the path.

Comment: I still am unable to upload the image to the php server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you replace this.photos with croppedImage? See the code below.

```
getImage()
{
  var options = {
   maximumImagesCount: 1,
   width: 800,
   height: 800,
   quality: 80,
  };

 this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
 .then((results) => {
   this.reduceImages(results).then((croppedImage) => {
        this.photos = croppedImage;

        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

            let d = new Date();
            let time = d.getTime();
            let options_f: FileUploadOptions = {
              fileKey: 'file',
              fileName: this.name + time + '.jpg',
              chunkedMode: false,
              mimeType: "image/jpg",
            };

            let url='https://elevather.com/mentor/file_upload.php';

            fileTransfer.upload(this.photos, url, options_f)
            .then((data) => {
              if(data["_body"]=="yes")
                this.msg = 'yes';
              else
                this.msg = 'no';
            }, (err) => {
              console.log('upload failed!');
            });

    }, (err) => { });
  }, (err) => { });
}

reduceImages(selected_pictures: any) : any{
  return selected_pictures.reduce((promise:any, item:any) => {
    return promise.then((result) => {
      return this.cropService.crop(item, {quality: 80})
       .then(cropped_image => cropped_image);
     });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. Maybe there might be some problem in my php server code or maybe the image has to be encoded in some format. Can you suggest what it could be?

Comment: put some logs to your php server and see if you receive the image details and other helpful informations.

Comment: I have put some code that should create a file and add some data to it. But the file isn't being created.

Comment: the question is if the app sends the correct data to your php server. if yes, than you have some mistakes there, if not, still an app issue.